# NGINX fails to start after update to K/Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, kubuntu

You'll get only a cryptic `nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'` in */var/log/syslog*.

Answer (score 0):

The distro upgrade/update will install and start up Apache alongside Nginx.
Stop and or uninstall Apache and Nginx starts normally.